# Aliasing modules using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, require, commonjs

Some context here: **It's not that I cannot use Webpack, it's that I do not want to use Webpack**. I would like to keep everything as "vanilla" as possible.

Currently when creating modules in a project you have to require them using either a relative or absolute path, for example in the following directory..

```
project/
├── index.js
├── lib/
│   ├── network/
│   │      request.js
│   │      response.js
├── pages/
│   ├── foo.js
```

Considering we're in index.js we would import request via

```
var networkRequest = require('./lib/network/request.js')
```

and if we're in foo.js we would import request via

```
var networkRequest = require('../lib/network/request.js')
```

What I'm wondering is that if there's any way to perhaps, set a local alias in `Package.json` or anywhere else like so:

```
localPackages = [
    { name: 'network-request', path: './lib/network/request.js' }
];
```

In which you could just do

```
var networkRequest = require('network-request')
```

From any file and it will provide the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, that's what [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) is for. Native and out of the box.

You can also set [local paths](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths) in package.json

```
{
  "name": "baz",
  "dependencies": {
    "bar": "file:../foo/bar"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not working, unfortunately: 

`"dependencies": {
    "react": "15.3.2",
    "react-native": "0.35.0",
    "@components/RootTabBar": "file:./src/components/RootTabBar"
  },`

Getting the "Unable to resolve module" error.

Comment: I'm not sure the syntax @components/RootTabBar *should* resolve.  I've never seen a module name with special characters other than hyphens in it.

Comment: Here's a large variety: https://www.npmjs.com/~exponent  -- I also tried with regular names, IE: "RootTabBar" but that didn't work either.